# WP APP Customize Syndicationfeed

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, rss

i'm trying to customize the sample RSS Reader app from msdn ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh487167(v=vs.105).aspx ).
The problem is - that i don't know how to access the Syndicationfeed for adding more Elements which should be displayed.
In my case i'd like to implement the picture from this part of the XML RSS File but i can't access it, or add it via Syndicationfeed(I'd like to have the image displayed before the other contents of the .

```
<media:content medium="image" url="http://img.scoop.it/6g20xV_r85c7e0LBx21A_jl72eJkfbmt4t8yenImKBV9ip2J1EIeUzA9paTSgKmv">
    <media:title>Gartner Positions Informatica MDM as a Visionary in 2014 Magic Quadrant for Master Data Management of Product Data Solutions Informatica Corporation :: AD HOC NEWS</media:title>
  </media:content>
```

I'm new to Windows Phone Development and C# Development so I'm having some trouble implementing this.

thanks in advance!

Comment: You are trying to get some rss feed and then modify the XML-response? Or i wrong understand your question?

Comment: hi, i was trying to implement a rss feed into a app and customize the layout, which is not easy without knowledge of wp app dev or c#...
I now implemented a PhoneApplicationPage where i've insert the data from the rss xml file. The problem i have right now is, when i'm navigating from one page to another the browser doesn't track the history and i can't use the back button correctly =(